# OnLoad event oninherited form does not gets called

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance

I have 3 forms

1. `FormBase` which has no `onload event`
2. `FormBaseDetail : FormBase` ->
   on this form I used the visual designer to create an `on_load event`
3. `FormBoxDetail : FormBaseDetail` ->
   on this form I also used the visual designer to create an on `load event`

When `FormBoxDetail` is created, the `onload event` on `FormBaseDetail` is called but not the `onload event` on `FormBoxDetail`. This is never called.

What am i doing wrong ?

```
public partial class FormBase : Form
{
    public FormBase()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

public partial class FormBaseDetail : FormBase
{
    public FormBaseDetail()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void FormBaseDetail_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("FormBaseDetail");
    }
}

public partial class FormBoxDetail : Test_app.FormBaseDetail
{
    public FormBoxDetail()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void FormBoxDetail_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("why am i not getting called");
    }
}
```

Comment: Goto FormBoxDetail.designer.cs and see whether `FormBoxDetail_Load` is mapped to `this.Load` event or not.

Comment: @GuidoG as you can see different event handler is used for Load event - FormBox_Load instead of FormBoxDetail_Load

Comment: @GuidoG there is no `FormBaseBox` in your code. And there is no `FormBaseList` in your code

Comment: Edited my question, toke some time because some guy called Sergey was editing my code

Comment: @GuidoG some guy called Sergey was making dirty work for removing useless namespace definitions from your code and making it readable. Still no `FormBaseBox` in your code

Comment: found this in FormBoxDetail.Designer.cs this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.FormBoxDetail_Load); So the event is property coupled ?

Comment: @Sergey, there should not be a FormBaseBox in the code, that was what I was trying to fix while you where doing my dirty work... It has to be FormBoxDetail in stead of formBaseBox

Comment: @GuidoG I asked this question 9 minutes ago, and you are the only who edited this question since then. Please do required updates

Comment: @Sergey, the code should be ok now ? What do you mean with "please do required updates" ? I do not understand you question to me. (English is not my native language)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only two reasons why Load event can be not fired:

1. Event handler `FormBoxDetail_Load` is not attached to `Load` event. But you are saying its not your case.
2. You are not loading `FormBoxDetail`. Make sure you are creating instance of `FormBoxDetail` class. Probably you are using `FormBaseDetail` instead. Make sure you are using correct form class.

Here both event handlers will be fired:

```
var form = new FormBoxDetail();
form.Show();
```

First one is a `FormBaseDetail_Load` handler, and then goes `FormBoxDetail_Load` handler.

Comment: form is created like this FormBoxDetail form = new FormBoxDetail();
and in FormBoxDetail.Designer.cs there is this this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.FormBoxDetail_Load);

Comment: FormBoxDetail has user controls on it like textboxes and stuff that FormBaseDetail has not, so I can be sure the right form is loaded

Comment: @GuidoG just tried your code. If correct form is created and both event handlers attached, then I see two message boxes.

Comment: I do not understand why this works with you and not with me. I stripped the forms to only have the code you can see in my question and here it still does not work. I am using visual studio 2013 with framework 4.5

Comment: @GuidoG here is my [zipped solution](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17614827/WindowsFormsApplication1.zip) try it please

Comment: Sergey, I made a new project and copied the 3 forms in the new project, and guess what. It WORKS there. So there must be some strange setting in the current project. It is a project I have inherited from another programmer that left the building, so I guess I am <censured> now...

Comment: OK, I removed the 3 forms from the curernt project, cleaned solution and rebuild solution. Than I added the forms back to the project, cleaned solution and rebuild solution, and now it works. Don't know why, don't know what the difference is but it works again for now.

Comment: @GuidoG sorry, its hard to tell what might went wrong in your legacy project, but basically you need to verify these two things - event subscription and correct form class

Answer (score 0):

It just happen to me, when, from one executable project I instantiated (new) a class e.a. MyClasss c = new MyDll.MyClass(par), and the Form did not load.
I found that I forgot to load it:
Application.Run(c);

Regards